# Move image smoothly according to the movement of a device

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

So, here is the deal. I want to create a little game-like app(let me call it **the game**, from now on). Before I begin, I'd like to show you up the raw UI of the game.

[image]

So, as you can see, I would have:

- a red ball in the middle
- two walls on either sides

**Procedure:**

1. User would move the device to right side and hits the right wall (the gray ball on the right side is simulated)
2. Movement of device occures to left so it can reach the left wall as well. (like the gray ball on the left)

All I know regarding the program side is the sensors, especially `Accelerometers`. Most of the people at Stackoverflow are of the opinion that working with sensors not on its good stages, that is, the data comes from them is very noisy, processing them can be hard. However, I think a lot of games are using them to some extent...

Well, I tried moving an image by drawing it. I attempted to get data from `gyroscope`, `accelerometer`, `linear accelerometer` and used that data to draw my image. The problem is that if I move the device smoothly and slowly then I got almost no movement on the drawings. That gives the horrible user experience.

The question is how can I implement my game so that it can meet all my needs above even if I move my device slowly. Any approaches are welcome.

Comment: Have a look at `https://code.google.com/p/android-acceleroscroll/`

Comment: That seems to be of a great help. I'll implement it soon. Thanks

Comment: If it can satisfy your requirement after implementation,let me know so that I can post it as an answer and make it helpful to other developers in future.